# How to correctly display Japanese RTF Fonts

Tags: delphi, unicode, fonts, rtf

I am working on an application in Delphi 2009 which makes heavy use of RTF, edited using TRichEdit and TLMDRichEdit. Users who entered Japanese text in these RTF controls have been submitting intermittent reports about the Japanese text being displayed as gibberish when reloading the content, both on Win XP and Vista, with Eastern Language Support installed.

Typically, English and Japanese is mixed and is mostly displayed without a problem, for example:

```
Inventory turns partnerships.  在庫回転率の
```

(my apologies if the Japanese text is broken incorrectly - I do not speak or read the language).

Quite frequently however, only the Japanese portion of the text will be gibberish, for example:

```
ŒÉñ?“]-¦Œüã‚Ì·•Ê‰?-vˆö‚ðŽû‰v‚ÉŒø‰?“I‚ÉŒ‹‚Ñ‚Â‚¯‚é’mŽ¯‚ª‘÷Ý‚·‚é?(マーケットセクター、
見込み客の優  先順位と彼らに販売する知識)
```

From extensive online searching, it appears that the problem is as a result of the fonts saved as part of the RTF. Fonts present on Japanese language version of Windows is not necessarily the same as a US English version. It is possible to programmatically replace the fonts in the RTF file which yields an almost acceptable result, i.e.

```
-D‚‚ｽƒIƒyƒŒ[ƒVƒ・“‚ﾆƒƒWƒXƒeƒBƒbƒN‚ﾌƒpƒtƒH[ƒ}ƒ“ƒX‚-˜‰v‚ﾉŒ‹‚ﾑ‚ﾂ‚ｯ‚ﾈ‚｢‚±ﾆ‚ﾍ?A‘‚｢‚ﾉ-ｳ‘ﾊ‚ﾅ‚ ‚驕B‚ｻ‚‚ﾍAl“ｾ‚ｵ‚ｽ・‘P‚ﾌˆﾛ‚ƒƒXƒN‚ﾉ‚ｳ‚‚ｷB
```

However, there are still quite a few "junk" characters in there which are not correctly recognized as Japanese characters. Looking at the raw RTF you'll see the following:

```
-D\'82\'82\u65405?\'83I\'83y\'83\'8c[\'83V\'83\u12539?\ldblquote\'82\u65414?
```

Clearly, the Unicode characters are rendered correctly, but for example the \'82\'82 pair of characters should be something else? My guess is that it actually represents a double byte character of some sort, which was for some mysterious reason encoded as two separate characters rather than a single Unicode character.

Is there a generic, (relatively) foolproof way to take RTF containing Eastern Languages and reliably displaying it again?

*For completeness sake, I updated the RTF font table in the following way:*

- Replaced the font name "?l?r ?o?S?V?b?N;" with "\'82\'6c\'82\'72 \'82\'6f\'83\'53\'83\'56\'83\'62\'83\'4e;"
- Updated font names by replacing "\froman\fprq1\fcharset0 " with "\fnil\fprq1\fcharset128 "
- Updated font names by replacing "\froman\fprq1\fcharset238 " with "\fnil\fprq1\fcharset128 "
- Updated font names by replacing "\froman\fprq1 " with "\fnil\fprq1\fcharset128 "
- Replacing font name "?? ?????;" with "\'82\'6c\'82\'72 \'82\'6f\'83\'53\'83\'56\'83\'62\'83\'4e;"

Update: Updating font names alone wont make a difference. The locale seems to be the big problem. I have seen a few site discussing ways around converting the display of Japanese RTF to something most reader would handle, but I haven't found a solution yet, see for example:
[here](http://bbs.wankuma.com/index.cgi?mode=al2&namber=6185&KLOG=6) and [here](http://www.bekkoame.ne.jp/~n-iyanag/nisus/tips/macRTFtoWin.html).

Comment: Font name \'82l\'82r \'82o\'83S\'83V\'83b\'83N is shown as `'MS PGothic'` when opened with Wordpad on Windows 10. When opened with LibreOffice, or with Wordpad on Win 7, it is shown as `'ＭＳ Ｐゴシック'`.

Comment: Note that the font name ?l?r ?o?S?V?b?N; in your question seems to be already corrupt, I guess that it is \'82l\'82r \'82o\'83S\'83V\'83b\'83N in a previous state of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that changing font names in the RTF has probably made things worse.  If a font specified in the RTF is not a Unicode font, then surely the characters due to be rendered in that font will be encoded as Shift-JIS, not as Unicode. And then so will the other characters in the text. So treating the whole thing as Unicode, or appending Unicode text, will cause the corruption you see. You need to establish whether RTF you import is encoded Shift-JIS or Unicode, and also whether the machine you are running on (and therefore D2009 default input format) is Japanese or not. In Japan, if a text file has no Unicode BOM it would usually be Shift-JIS (but not always).

Comment: Further investigation did show that changing the font is not a good idea. Specifically, Changing the specified charset is a no-no , since \fcharset0 is ANSI and \fcharset128 is Shift-JIS. On the surface at least, it looks like swapping between different fonts with different charsets would allow you to correctly encode what the user entered. Unfortunately, it still does not quite explain why the RTF control can't figure out the correct display.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing something similar, but not with Japanese fonts.  Just special characters like micro (as in microliters) and superscripts.  The problem was that even though the RTF string I was sending to the user from an ASP.NET webpage was correct (I could see the encoded RTF stream using Fiddler2), when MS Word actually opened the RTF, it added a bunch of garbage escape codes like what I see in your sample.

What I did was to run the entire RTF text through a conversion routine that swapped all characters over ascii 127 to their special unicode point equivalent.  So I would get something like \uc1\u181? (micro) for the special characters.  When I did that, Word was able to open the file no problem.  Ironically, it re-encoded the \uc1\uxxx? back to their RTF escaped equivalents.

```
Private Function ConvertRtfToUnicode(ByVal value As String) As String

    Dim ch As Char() = value.ToCharArray()
    Dim c As Char
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    Dim code As Integer

    For i As Integer = 0 To ch.Length - 1
        c = ch(i)
        code = Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW(c)
        If code <= 127 Then
            'Don't need to replace if one of your typical ASCII codes
            sb.Append(c)
        Else
            'MR: Basic idea came from here http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=33935981&threadid=33935972
            '  swaps the character for it's Unicode decimal code point equivalent
            sb.Append(String.Format("\uc1\u{0:d}?", code))
        End If
    Next

    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

Not sure if that will help your problem, but it's working for me.

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! I tried something similar initially, but it made no difference as the RTF character stream itself did not contain any Unicode. This is however still an extremely useful function to keep around.